# Display 3 Maximum values of a Column, include duplicate values with condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display Highest 3 marks on each classes, I am using following code.

```
SELECT Name, Marks FROM mytable AS t1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(Marks) AS best_marks FROM mytable WHERE Class='class1' ORDER BY Marks DESC LIMIT 3) AS t2
ON t1.Marka = t2.best_marks ORDER BY Marks DESC, Name ASC;
```

This code has given by 'Eggplant' from Stackoverfolow.

It will works fine when there is no Class.

My Table is

```
Name     Marks     Class
S1       90        class1 
S2       55        class3
S3       60        class4
S4       90        class1
S5       55        class2
S6       60        class3
S7       88        class1    
S8       45        class6  
S9       88        class1
s10      76        class3
s11      92        class3
s12      44        class1
```

Like aforesaid table, I want to show 3 records include duplicate records and class

So my final output looks like

```
Name     Marks     Class
S1       90        class1 
S4       90        class1
S7       88        class1    
S9       88        class1

Name     Marks     Class
S5       55        class2

Name     Marks     Class
s11      92        class3
s10      76        class3
S6       60        class3


Name     Marks     Class
S3       60        class4

Name     Marks     Class
S8       45        class6
```

Kindly please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to approach this problem.  The following puts the distinct `Marks` for each class into a list and takes the first three of them.  It then compares the `Marks` in the data to that list:

```
select t1.*
from t1 join
     (select class, substring_index(group_concat(distinct Marks order by Marks desc), ',', 3) as Marks3
      from mytable t1
      group by class
     ) tc
     on t1.class = tc.class and find_in_set(t1.Marks, tc.Marks3) > 0
order by class, Marks desc;
```